# How do I get encoding = "utf-8"?> in a txmldocument.xml?

Tags: delphi, txmldocument

This doesn't work for me in Delphi XE2.

```
Var
  XMLDoc : IXMLDOCUMENT;
begin
  XMLDoc := NewXMLDocument;
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
  XMLDoc.Version := '1.0';
  XMLDoc.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XMLDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  Memo1.Text := XMLDoc.XML.Text;
```

I still do NOT get the `encoding="utf-8"?>` in the resulting doc. But if I say

```
  XMLDoc.Encoding := 'utf-16';
```

then it I do get `encoding="utf-16"?>` in the resulting doc.

Any ideas? Anyone?

Answer (score 7):

UTF-8 is XML's default encoding when no `encoding` attribute or BOM are present to indicate a different encoding is being used.  The underlying XML engine knows that, so it will omit generating an `encoding` attribute for UTF-8 when it knows it is safe to do so.

AFAIK, there is no way to force `IXMLDocument.XML.Text` or `IXMLDocument.SaveToXML(var XML: DOMString)` or `IXMLDocument.SaveToXML(var XML: WideString)` to generate an `encoding` attribute for UTF-8.  However, `IXMLDocument.SaveToXML(var XML: UTF8String)` and `IXMLDocument.SaveToStream()` do generate an `encoding` attribute for UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks to other postings on SO, I discovered that the problem is because of the `Memo1.Text` which is UFT-16. By changing the last line to `XMLDoc.SaveToStream(MyStream)`, where `MyStream := TFileStream.Create('test.XML', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);` the utf-8 indicator is included in the resulting file. Yay.

Answer (score 0):

After generate Xml File Make Format and save it will save as UTF8

```
     Procedure FormatXMLFile(const XmlFile:string);
var
   oXml : IXMLDocument;
 begin
   oXml := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
   oXml.LoadFromFile(XmlFile);
   oXml.XML.Text:=Xml. xmlDoc.FormatXMLData(oXml.XML.Text);
   oXml.Active := true;
   oXml.SaveToFile(XmlFile);
 end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).